# How to set NgForm value in Observable and test that it was set?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, testing

I'm trying to test `NgForm` and check if form's value is set when store's state is updated.

```
@ViewChild('form') form: NgForm;

ngOnInit() {
this.subscription = this.store.select('shoppingList').subscribe(data => {
    this.editedItem = data.editedIngredient;
    this.form.setValue({ 
      name: this.editedItem.name,
      amount: this.editedItem.amount
    })
});
```

}

But when setting the value I'm getting

```
There are no form controls registered with this group yet.  
If you're using ngModel, you may want to check next tick (e.g. use setTimeout).
```

Also tried to create fake form and set it instead of `NgForm`

`TestBed.createComponent(ShoppingEditComponent).debugElement.componentInstance.form = { value: {}, setValue: (newValue) => { this.value = newValue }};`

but in the test it's value is never updated, getting empty `value` object.

What's the best approach to testing such case?

Answer (score 0):

> @ViewChild('form') form: NgForm;

will be not available in ngOnInit lifecycle hook.

First, you need to create a form, either in constructor or in ngOnInit.

And only then you can perform methods on existing form.

Example

```
export class MyComponent {
  form: FormGroup;
  editedItem;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
    this.subscribeToShoppingList();
  }

  private createForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: null,
      amount: null
    });
  }

  private subscribeToShoppingList() {
    this.store.select('shoppingList').subscribe(data => {
      this.editedItem = data.editedIngredient;
      this.form.setValue({ 
        name: this.editedItem.name,
        amount: this.editedItem.amount
      });
    });
  }
}
```

In this case you don't need to test what Store returns to you, you would be good enough to unit test something like:

```
const mocks = {
  store: {
    select: sinon.stub().withArgs('shoppingList').returns(new Subject())
  }
};

let component: MyComponent;

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    component = new MyComponent(
      new FormBuilder(),
      <any> mocks.store
    );
  });

  describe('ngOnInit', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      component.ngOnInit();
    });

    it('should create form', () => {
      expect(component.form).to.be.instanceof(FormGroup);
    });

    it('should create form with correct fields', () => {
      expect(component.form.value).to.haveOwnProperty('name');
      expect(component.form.value).to.haveOwnProperty('amount');
    });

    it('should subscribe to store.shoppingList', () => {
      expect(component.store.select).to.be.calledOnce.and.calledWith('shoppingList');
    });

    it('should set correct data from store to component', () => {
      component.store.select.next({
        editedIngredient: {
          name: 'new',
          amount: 100
        }
      });

      expect(component.editedItem.amount.to.eql(100));

      expect(component.form.value.name).to.eql('new');
    });

  });
});
```

I have not tested the code, it may have problems, but i hope that i've explained the main idea.

Comment: Seems legit, but I don't want to change Template driven approach to Reactive.

Comment: You can't use form.setValue on template driven

Comment: But it works in a browser, issue is that just cannot write unit test for it :)